# Trying to hit an API with JSON data in REACT

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have just started learning to code in ReactJS and have come to the part where I need to hit an API to get back JSON data.

I am running this on a node server on my local which tries to build it each time I make a change - this helps because it shows me where my errors are. Unfortunately it doesn't mean I know why I am getting an error.

This is my code so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

var GetUnassignedClients = React.createClass({
    unassignedClients: function () {
        return $.getJSON('http://localhost/backoffice/?action=unassignedClients.getUnassingedClients')
            .then((data) => {
                this.setState({resultMe: data.results});
            });
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>this.state.resultMe</div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = GetUnassignedClients;
```

I will re-paste the bit that seems to be throwing the error:

```
return $.getJSON('http://localhost/backoffice/?action=unassignedClients.getUnassingedClients')
            .then((data) => {
                this.setState({resultMe: data.results});
            });
```

The error seems to be pointing at the $ - when I wrap this all in {} then it points to the full stop (.).

Not sure if I am doing something wrong or missing something.

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay turns out I was trying to use `$.getJSON` which is JQuery - due to building this on my local using a node server JQuery wasn't included on my local development before the production code was built.

So instead I looked into using fetch that seems to be the go to when coding in react.

I also moved this section into a componentDidMount function so the app would be loaded and then the API call would be made - not that I have a lot of data to load but it's good practice for when you do.

My working code for this section:

```
componentDidMount () {
        fetch("http://localhost/dashboard/?action=unassignedUsers.getUnassingedUsers", {
            credentials: 'same-origin'
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => this.setState({data: json}));
    }
```

I also came across a couple issues using fetch - if you need a session available to access said data then you need to specifically pass through the credentials or the API call will re-direct to the login page. At first I saw a status 200 but no data - as it successfully re-directed to the login page, but obviously there was no JSON to access here.

Answer (score 2):

The `$`in the `$.getJSON` is referring to jQuery. Do you have it included in your page? Javascript is trying to parse the dollar sign and can't find it. Other possible solution is to use a separate http library (if you don't need jQuery), such as [axiois](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) or [fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure, but I thought you would hit in this way

```
fetch(`http://localhost:8088/api/this/is/an/api/call`) 
.then(result=> {
this.setState({items:result.json()});
});
```